# Trouble eliminating white, no-data pixels on raster image in Leaflet.js, served via GeoServer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I'm learning leaflet.js, and want to be able to create a web map that can be used alongside GeoServer. My main problem now is eliminating a white background from my imported raster layer, brought in via `L.tileLayer.wms`. I have had this problem before, albeit with vector data, and I solved that problem by setting `transparent: true` and `zIndex: 2`, while the base map was set to `1`. When I set my new raster layer transparency and `zIndex` to those same parameter values, the whole layer disappears; now all I can see is my base map. All I can find online for eliminating this white background is to set the `zIndex` and to set `transparent: true`. Hoping someone out there has encountered this issue before and can teach me something I'm missing.

Attached is my code sample:

```
var esri = L.esri.basemapLayer('Imagery').addTo(map);

var test_layer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/learn_js/wms',{
    layers: 'learn_js:geotiff_coverage',
    format: 'image/png',
    zIndex: 2,
    transparent: true
  //opacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Are you running your own geoserver instance? Is the WMS layer transparent using any other WMS client? You should check first if the problem is in the generation of the WMS images or on the display side.

Comment: When I turn `transparent` to` false` the image shows perfectly, albeit with a white background which covers the entire base map. And yea I'm running the GeoServer instance. I haven't tried using any other service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the raster image I am using. I switched raster images to one within my area of interest, and now the image appears to be loading with background pixels eliminated. I still do not know why one works and the other does not, but at least I know there were no coding or geoserver issues at fault. Perhaps something with the internal structure of the raster image was causing this hangup. I do know that with my original image, the tile layer preview within the geoserver dashboard would not display the image as a png, but would as a jpeg. With my new image, geoserver's tile layer preview displays the image in all formats.